# Replace backslash with double backslash

Tags: java, string

I want to change the backslash in a string to double backslash.

I have

```
String path = "C:\Program Files\Text.txt";
```

and I want to change it to

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Text.txt"
```

Comment: Doesn't that say syntax error?

Comment: Always use `/` instead of \\ for file-system paths, since `/` is OS-independent.

Comment: You don't have (1), because it doesn't compile: therefore you don't have the problem of converting it to (2). What you probably have is a string that contains single backslashes, derived not from a literal, but say from the user, which is already usable as it is. The double backslashes are only required for string literals, and they are converted to single by the compiler. You don't have this problem. Not a real question.

Answer (score 23):

`replaceAll` is using regex, and since you don't need to use regex here simply use

```
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

`\` is special in String literals. For instance it can be used to

- create special characters like tab `\t`, line separators `\n` `\r`,
- or to write characters using notation like `\uXXXX` (where `X` is hexadecimal value and `XXXX` represents position of character in Unicode Table).

To escape it (and create `\` character) we need to add another `\` before it.
So String literal representing `\` character looks like `"\\"`. String representing two `\` characters looks like `"\\\\"`.

Answer (score 9):

Using [**String#replace()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String s= "C:\\Program Files\\Text.text";
System.out.println(s.replace("\\", "\\\\"));
```

Comment: I am getting error as "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1"

Comment: @user2060390 you are probably using replaceAll. you don't really need a regex solution here just use replace() which expects a string and an replacement string.

Comment: `System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"));` would work if you want to use `replaceAll`.

Comment: If you want to use replaceAll try this: 'System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"));' however i strongly recommend to use non-regex String#replace solution in this case. :)

Comment: I am getting the path of the file using "Paths.get(selfile)" and iam passing it as input for "PDDOcument.load(input)".

Comment: replacing the "real backslash" with the "actual backslash, for real this time"   http://xkcd.com/1638/