# How to get File Path with double-backslashes in Java

Tags: java, filepath

I have a program where I save school grades in a .txt File.
I want to let the user choose where this File should be saved.
It works with the JFileChooser find but Java have a problem with the
FilePath.
The filepath from the JFileChooser looks like this:
C:\Users...\Documents\n.txt
But if I want to read the TextFile in the Program Java says that
it couldn't find the Filepath.
It should look like this:
C:\Users\...\Documents\n.txt

How can I get the Path with double-backslashes?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
            jf.showSaveDialog(null);
            String fPath = jf.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            fPath.replaceAll('\', '\\');

            System.out.println(p);

        }
```

that does not work it says invalid character constant

Comment: pls add your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace backslash with double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041111/replace-backslash-with-double-backslash)

Comment: When you use `getSelectedFile` or `getSelectedFiles` on the file chooser object you get the `File` objects. You can use these to create a `FileInputStream` and read the files. Adding a bit of code helps us in identifying an issue.

Comment: The Replacing method replac() does not work

Comment: @AlarmfürCobra11 You're kidding. Of course it works. The stuff in the JDK/JRE is among the most tested code on the planet. It may not work *for you,* but in that case you need to provide *your code*.

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
    jf.showSaveDialog(null);
    String fPath = jf.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    fPath.replaceAll('\', '\\');
    
    System.out.println(p);
   
   }

Comment: You need to provide your code *in the question.* You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible in a comment.

Comment: that doesnt work it says 'Invalid character constant'

Answer (score 2):

There are some places where the backslash serves as escape character, and must be escaped, to be simply the backslash of a Windows path separator.

These places are inside .properties files, java String literals and some more.

You could for Windows paths alternatively use a slash (POSIX compliance of Windows).

```
        fPath = fPath.replace('\\', '/');
```

Backslash:

```
        fPath = fPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

The explanation is that a single backslash inside char and string literals must be escaped: two backslashes represent a single backslash.

With regular expressions (replaceAll) a backlash is used as command: a digit is expressed as `\d` and as java String: `"\\d"`. Hence the backslash itself becomes (behold):

```
        fPath = fPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"); // PLEASE NOT
```

***I almost did not see it, but methods on String do not alter it, but return a new value, so one needs to assign the result.***

Answer (score 1):

When using hard coded file names in Java you should *always* use forward slashes `/` as file separators. Java knows how to handle them on Windows.

Also you should not use *absolute paths*. You don't know if that paths will exist at the target system. You should use either *relative paths* starting with your classpath as root "/..." or get some system dependen places from `System.getProperty()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues in your code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
        jf.showSaveDialog(null);
        String fPath = jf.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        // fPath is a proper file path. This can be used directly with
        // new File(fPath). The contents will contain single \ character
        // as Path separator
        fPath.replaceAll('\', '\\');
        // I guess you are trying to replace a single \ character with \\
        // character. You need to escape the \ character. You need to
        // consider that both parameters are regexes.
        // doing it is:
        // fPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
        // And then you need to capture the return value. Strings are 
        // immutable in java. So it is:
        // fPath = fPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
        System.out.println(p);
        // I don't know what p is. I guess you want to use fPath
    }
```

That said, I do not understand why you want to convert the path returned by `JFileChooser`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the file path with double backslashes in Java. Double backslashes are for:

1. The Java compiler, inside string literals.
2. The Java regex compiler.

Everywhere else you can obtain backslashes, or use forward slashes.

Possibly you are looking for `java.util.Properties`?

Comment: I mean that the filepath must be set by the user because the program shouldn't only work on one PC

Comment: I have no idea what this means. You are neither the Java compiler nor the regular expression compiler: you therefore have no identifiable nor identified need for double backslashes; and if you do, `java.util.Properties` will provide them to you.